# Послать сообщение в skype чат используя python

Tags: python, skype, python-2.7

Необходимо написать программу на Python для отправления сообщений в чат Skype. Skype4Py не подходит из-за того, что стоит 64-битный Python.

Существуют ли какие-либо альтернативы для работы со Skype, помимо Skype4Py, и есть ли Skype API для отправки сообщений?

Comment: какие либы птиона  есть кроме  Skype4Py  для работы со скайпом? Есть ли АПИ для отправки сообщений ?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [need an python script that uses skype4py to send an instant message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536146/need-an-python-script-that-uses-skype4py-to-send-an-instant-message)

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536146/need-an-python-script-that-uses-skype4py-to-send-an-instant-message

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Скайп-бот](https://gist.github.com/zed/5b7542e7acb2c716c606385966f3a51a) может послать сообщение, используя [REST API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/docs/api/chat#Activities):

```
POST /v2/conversations/8:alice/activities HTTP/1.1
Host: apis.skype.com
Authorization: Bearer <redacted oauth2 token>
{
  "message": {"content" : "Hi! (wave)"}
}
```

например чтобы послать `message` строку `skypeid` пользователю на Питоне:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import json
from urllib2 import urlopen, Request

def send_message(message, skypeid, token, host='apis.skype.com'):
    url = 'https://{host}/v2/conversations/8:{skypeid}/activities'.format(**vars())
    headers = dict(Authorization='Bearer ' + token)
    data = json.dumps(dict(message=dict(content=message))).encode()
    urlopen(Request(url, data, headers)).close()
```

где `token` можно получить с помощью другого http POST запроса:

```
from urllib import urlencode

def get_access_token(client_id, client_secret):
    # from messaging/auth-service.js in skype-sdk
    # NOTE: unlike the documented way in /skype/bots/docs/;
    #  this approach works for me
    url = 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'
    data = urlencode(dict(client_id=client_id,
                          scope='https://graph.microsoft.com/.default',
                          grant_type='client_credentials',
                          client_secret=client_secret)).encode()
    return json.loads(urlopen(url, data).read().decode())['access_token']
```

`access_token` можно кэшировать `expires_in` секунд.

Чтобы получить `client_id`, `client_secret` необходимо [зарегистрировать приложение со своей microsoft учётной записью и создать пароль](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/?mkt=en-us#/appList).

Затем сам [Skype бот нужно также зарегистрировать](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/manage), чтобы получить ссылку, по которой можно добавить бота в Skype-контакты (до публикации бота, по этой ссылке его можно найти).

Чтобы получить ответные сообщения нужно указать при создании Skype бота https webhook. Для теста, можно [`ngrok http 8000`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/docs/tutorials/simple-nodejs) использовать, который напечает url, который можно как публичный webhook указать. При этом достаточно локально http (не https) сервер запустить, который json может принимать, на указанном 8000 порту, например:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from aiohttp import web  # $ pip install aiohttp

async def handle(request):
    messages = await request.json()
    for message in messages:
        print(message)
    return web.HTTPCreated()  # 201

app = web.Application()
app.router.add_route('POST', '/v1/chat', handle)
web.run_app(app, host='localhost', port=8000, ssl_context=None)
```

В тему статья на Хабрахабр: [Как создать своего бота для Skype. Что не написано в документации](https://habrahabr.ru/post/281296/).

Comment: а можно поподробнее расписать, как создать свой сервер?

Comment: Уже вторые сутки бьюсь над этим вопросом, но найденный материал настолько обширный, а опыта в этом настолько мало, что я теряюсь где то в процессе создания сервера по туториалу. https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/bots/docs/tutorials/simple-nodejs вот пытаюсь по этой инструкции создать сервер, но запутался на теме 
Create server.js

Comment: @Vindict: любой http-сервер, которому json в POST запросе послать можно подойдёт. Для пробы можно хоть с `ncat -k -l 8000` команды начать (запросы в терминал печатаются). Вот [пример бота, который Morse код туда/сюда переводит](https://gist.github.com/zed/5b7542e7acb2c716c606385966f3a51a)

Comment: На 17.01.2019 OAuth возвращает токен со словами 'The provided 'OAuth' ticket failed authentication.' ЧТо изменилось?