# Авторизация по протоколу OAuth. Автоматическое получение access token для vk

Tags: vkontakte-api, oauth, python-3.5

Имеется standalone десктопное приложение для vk. Авторизация проходит по способу Implicit flow по протоколу OAuth 2.0. После успешной авторизации я получаю access_token в URL-фрагменте ссылки. На данный момент я после каждой авторизации или по истечению срока действия access_token копирую токен из url вручную, то есть это должны будут делать и пользователи. Для меня задачей является реализовать в своей программе данный способ авторизации, но в автоматизированном виде (автоматическое извлечение токена для пользователя приложения), но извлечение токена напрямую из ссылки в силу множества ограничений является затруднительной и непонятной для меня задачей. Одно из таких затруднений это то, что нужно использовать некую среду, внутри которой есть свой компонент браузера.

Я нашел в интернете методы извлечения access_token путем притворства браузером (https://github.com/dzhioev/vk_api_auth), но в данном методе требуется ручной ввод пароля и логина, да и авторизация проходит не по протоколу OAuth (Еще вопросом для меня является можно ли сохранить данные, введенные пользователем для авторизации).

Также нашел другой модуль для авторизации (https://github.com/dimka665/vk), но для меня, как новичка, он сложен и я не понимаю как он работает (каким образом происходит авторизация) и как его использовать в своей программе. Если возможно, объясните, пожалуйста, как его можно применить на практике.

Следующий модуль описан на хабре - https://habrahabr.ru/post/201074/. Он идеально подходит для меня, но он написан для C# в среде MS Visual Studio, а я пишу программу на Python 3.5. В данном модуле используется WebAuthenticationBroker (специальный класс который запускает стандартное окно в котором открывается ссылка для авторизации) (Рисунок 1). Есть ли аналог чего-то подобного в Python 3.5?

[image: Рисунок 1]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как разрешить данную задачу и какие ваши мысли по этому вопросу.

Comment: если руками реализовывать без подручных библиотек, то посмотрите как `get_access_token()` используется в [skype боте](https://gist.github.com/zed/5b7542e7acb2c716c606385966f3a51a) (с oauth2): [Послать сообщение в skype чат используя python](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/524924/23044)

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, в мире Python ничего посоветовать не могу, однако я тоже сталкивался с необходимостью авторизации в VK по OAuth2 из десктопного (в моем случае - консольного) приложения, но написанного на Java. Решил следующим образом:

1. Для авторизации избирается путь мимикрии под веб-приложение, поэтому на `https:// vk.com/apps?act=manage` создал веб-приложение и скопировал его App ID и Secret Key.
2. Передаю эти параметры в командной строке во время запуска консольного приложения. Оно, в свою очередь, стартует простой легковесный HTTP сервер с произвольным портом. Задача этого сервера - обработать callback запрос от `oauth.vk.com` и принять код авторизации, который, с помощью VK SDK, нужно будет обменять на токен.
3. Открыть дефолтный веб браузер системы и направить его на сервер авторизации, передав адрес локального callback сервера и параметры приложения из командной строки (параметром запроса scope запрашиваем права приложения, например `photos,audio`:

   `https:// oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=app_id&display=page&scope=<scopes_list>&redirect_uri=http:// localhost:39893/callback&response_type=code&v=5.52`
4. В окне браузера отобразится диалог авторизации приложения, а затем осуществится переход на локальный сервер:

   `http:// localhost:39893/callback?code=0d2dfec6f27514bb17`
5. обработчик запроса извлекает параметр запроса `code` и передает его клиенту авторизации для получения токена.
6. HTTP сервер продолжает работать, так как в нем зарегистрирован еще один обработчик `/captcha` для возможной обработки капчи, запрошенной VK API.

В итоге получается очень легкая для конечного пользователя авторизация в VK и не происходит компрометирование данных аккаунта.

Исходники описанного полного цикла авторизации на Java (если от них может быть польза) лежат здесь - https://github.com/axsy/vkdump , скринкаст описанного процесса авторизации здесь - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9VAWSWPKQYM.

Comment: спасибо, попробую реализовать мб как появится свободное время и как поднаберусь опыта, на данный момент я пока реализовал авторизацию методом, описанным в первой ссылке моего вопроса. Я новичок в программировании, поэтому данный способ пока я не знаю как реализовать на практике.

Comment: идея показалось мне интересной, но вот что делать, если сайт не позволяет использовать `HTTP` в `redirect_uri`, а только HTTP**S**?