# OAuth2 авторизация для Standalone

Tags: java, авторизация, oauth, oauth2

Все статьи про OAuth2, которые хоть как-то упоминают Standalone говорят лишь "перехватите *как-нибудь* код авторизации и отправьте POST запрос для получения токена". 
А вот как именно получить этот код, если я должен передать url в браузер, который с моим приложением никак не связан, нигде не объясняется. 
Как перехватить редирект содержащий в себе токен?

Конкретно в моём случае дилемма состоит в том, что я пишу реализацию API сайта (если ещё конкретнее, то реализацию на Java).

Моя цель реализовать удобный метод авторизации и дальнейшей работы с API.  
Желательно без "хаков" в виде эмуляции браузера и парсинга. А вполне легитимным способом. Возможно ли в данной ситуации автоматическое получение кода авторизации из браузера при подтверждении авторизации пользователем или придётся просить пользователя самостоятельно скопировать его из браузера и вставить в приложение?

Самое простое, что я вижу, это заменить метод авторизации с аргументами логин/пароль на метод авторизации через код авторизации и клиент id/secret.  
А что мне делать, если я, скажем, сам же захочу воспользоваться этой библиотекой и написать desktop-приложение?

Answer (score 2):

Как я понял, ваше **standalone**-приложение и есть **desktop**-приложение. В общем случае *как-нибудь* не получится, но есть метод, чтобы сделать это правильно. Весь секрет в том, что OAuth 2.0 не запрещает делать переадресацию на другие протоколы помимо http|https. Но в любом случае вам понадобится браузер (или его [встроенная версия, доступная в java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/embedded-browser-tutorial/overview.htm)).

Соответственно, вы отправляете пользователя на сервер авторизации, но при этом в адресе возврата указываете **свой** протокол, что-то вроде `myProtocol://что_то_тут_ещё`. [Такой подход предлагает к пример Яндекс](https://tech.yandex.com/oauth/doc/dg/reference/desktop-client-docpage/).

Однако это предполагает знание того, как зарегистрировать свой протокол в системе и т.д. Но от этого уже никуда не деться, и это совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: хотелось бы, всё таки, максимально автономного (портативного?) решения. К тому же, я сейчас попробовал отправить запрос на код авторизации с `redirect_uri=shikiauth://oauth2` (или с `redirect_uri=shikiauth%3A%2F%2Foauth2`) и запрос как-то вообще не сработал. По идее он должен был редиректнуть меня, а браузер запросить приложение с данным протоколом, нет?

Comment: нашёл вот такое решение для ВК АПИ, которое с небольшими правками подошло бы мне, если бы сайт принимал http, но он принимает только https (я уж было думал, что только его, но свой протокол тоже дало установить). Ну и `redirect_uri` в зарегистрированном приложении на сайте и при запросе должны совпадать, иначе ошибка вместо переадресации =/

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608693

я бы, наверное, мог использовать подобный локальный сервер, если бы можно было запустить в https (https://github.com/axsy/vkpe/tree/master/src/main/java/com/alekseyorlov/vkpe/web)

Comment: посмотрел заголовки при запросе с `redirect_uri=shikiauth://oauth2` и там возвращает код 302 =/

Comment: @mr.modest так и должно быть

Comment: пустое тело без намёка на код авторизации и 302 это нормально? и на сколько универсально такое решение? будет работать в Windows? Linux? Android?

Comment: @mr.modest очень туманны такие изъяснения, можешь их дополнить дополнительной информацией/скриншотами?

Comment: вот скриншот: http://pastexen.com/i/Tyoz7fGx20.png

Comment: сейчас попробовал прописать явно знакомый системе протокол (телеграма) `tg://` и заработало.. видимо пока в систему не прописать протокол, то браузер будет игнорировать протокол.. хех.. но вот вопрос по поводу кроссплатформенности такого решения остаётся открытым =/

Comment: @mr.modest судя по скриншоту, location он выставляет правильный. Касательно кроссплатформенности лучше задать отдельный вопрос с другими метками.