# Лишние пробелы при переводе в азбуку Морзе

Tags: python

Я создаю азбуку морзе на питоне. Если текст имеет пробел, в  версии азбуки морзе  текста добавляется тоже пробел, но питон находит откуда-то очень много пробелов.

```
dict1 = {"A":".-","B":"-...","C":"-.-.","D":"-..","E":".","F":"..-.","G":"--.","H":"....","I":"..","J":"-.-.","K":"-.-","L":".-..","M":"--",
          "N":"-.","O":"---","P":".--.","Q":"--.-","R":".-.","S":"...","T":"-","U":"..-","V":"...-","W":".--","X":".-..","Y":"-.--","Z":"--.."}
def change():
    global dict1
    crypt = ""
    text = input("[*]Enter text\n[text]>>>")
    for i in text:
        b = i.upper()
        for j in dict1:
            if b == " ":
                crypt += " "
            elif b == j:
                crypt += str(dict1.get(b))
    print("[+]Crypt text:\n" + str(crypt))
change()
```

Если запустить данный код, выведется в консоль это:

```
[*]Enter text
[text]>>>hello stackoveflow 
[+]Crypt text:
......-...-..---                          ...-.--.-.-.----...-...-..-..---.--
```

Почему питон находит так много пробелов, и как исправить код так, что бы текст  выводился через 1 пробел?

Comment: А вы зачем на пробел проверяете внутри цикла по словарю, вы пробел печатаете на каждой проверке в словаре. И кстати шифром это назвать сложно, расшифровать то это нельзя

Comment: И кстати, зачем вообще нужен цикл. вы можете получить просто `dict[i.upper()]` собственно словари для того и нужны

Comment: @True-hacker можно всё в одну строчку преобразование написать `crypto = ''.join([dict1.get(c.upper(), ' ') for c in text])`. А в вашем коде не верно что нужно сравнение на пробел вынести за цикл.

Comment: Мне кажется не с того вы свою карьеру "тру хакера" начинаете =)

Comment: @Mike Почему это нельзя расшифровать?

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч Я читал что питон полезная штука для хакинга . Разве не так?

Comment: Напишите в вопросе, что это азбука Морзе, чтобы не вводить людей в заблуждение.

Comment: @True-hacker Да Питон очень крутой язык и популярный :). А ваш шифр не расшифровать т.к. код Морзе не префиксный, т.е. если коды букв соединить то нельзя однозначно сообразить где разделить буквы. В этом смысле вам желательно разделять коды букв в результирующей строки пробелами.

Comment: можно в [скайп прикрутить бота, понимающего азбуку Морзе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/524924/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-skype-%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-python/525549#comment652714_525549)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пробел печатается много раз т.к. он добавляется внутри цикла, просто нужно проверку на пробел вынести за цикл. Но цикл не нужен вообще, не нужно итерировать по словарю и сравнивать каждый ключ, достаточно просто взять `dict1.get(b)`, либо если всё-таки нужно проверить есть ли ключ в словаре то нужно писать `if key in dict1`. Можно всё преобразование очень кратко на Питоне написать (второй параметр `get` означает значение по умолчанию, т.е. то что вернуть если в словаре не найдено):

`crypto = ''.join([dict1.get(c.upper(), ' ') for c in text])`